# How do i change the default text in Google Maps API Places Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is there a way to change the default text: "**Enter a location**" to 'Enter a Business Name' in [Google Maps API Places Autocomplete](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html)?

Answer (score 5):

You change the placeholder attribute on the input element.

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Business Name" />
```

Answer (score -1):

In the input field itself, add a value attribute as in:

```
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" value="foo">
```

Comment: I figured it out. You have to change the placeholder value of the input field.