# Change default text "Enter a Location" In Google Maps Places API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I've looked all over the internet trying to find an answer to my problem, and the closest thing I've found to an answer is another Stack Overflow question, here: [How do i change the default text in Google Maps API Places Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108499/how-do-i-change-the-default-text-in-google-maps-api-places-autocomplete)

The problem is that either the OP did not have quite the same requirements as myself, or they didn't quite make it clear if they do.

I'm looking for a way to take the default "Enter a Location" in the text input field, and replace it with something else *while keeping the same functionality*. i.e. have the text disappear on focus, and reappear when it loses focus if no text was entered.

In my current attempt, I've tried to replace the text using a jQuery plugin. It works visually on pageload, but when clicked, "Enter a Location" pops up again, and disappears when text is entered, or the input loses focus (as opposed to the text entry field going blank as intended).

Can anyone give me a pointer here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just set the `placeholder` attribute of the `input` element to which you are attaching the autocomplete to whatever you want:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Some new text">
```

This is detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#placeholder_text):

> By default, the text field created by the Autocomplete service
>   contains standard placeholder text. To modify the text, set the
>   placeholder attribute on the input element.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I can't believe I missed it way down at the bottom of the page there. I guess I wasn't using the right keywords to search.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. You may want to test it and see what happens in browsers that don't support the `placeholder` attribute (IE8 and below). I don't know what will happen there.

Comment: There's one minor hitch, where if the user enters text into the field, then removes it, it remains blank when it loses focus (as opposed to returning to the default I set in JQuery). This doesn't bother me too much, but is not the ideal situation.

Comment: @Douglas - I think you'll probably have to live with it. Who knows what's going on underneath the hood when you initialize the autocomplete (the default placeholder doesn't behave like a native placeholder, so it's definitely doing something to it). You can't really do any more than stick to the method outlined in the docs.

Comment: Is this possible in android app?