# Label animation (material angular) caussing problems with default text “Enter a Location” Google Maps Places API

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-places-api, angular-material

I have an `angular input text` which I use to select a location via Google Places API.
This is the input:

```
<md-input-container style="width: 30%;">
  <label>Location</label>
  <input type="text" id="gplace" googleplace>
</md-input-container>
```

In javascript I have a simple script to make the input works and retrieve locations using an `angular directive`.

The problem comes with the `label` "Location" and with the default `placeholder` (“Enter a Location”) that google provides. I'm able to remove that default `placeholder` by setting my own `placeholder` (i.e. to blank, which's what I finally need) in order to not show anything as [this question solves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379192/change-default-text-enter-a-location-in-google-maps-places-api). But if I do this, the label animation "stops working" and the mentioned `label` remains above all the time whether I insert text or not.

I've also tried to remove the placeholder using `jQuery` and doing something like `$('#elem').removeAttr('placeholder');` but it doesn't do the trick.

So, what I need is the label animation working fine without any text inside the input.

[Here is a simple working plunker of the input](https://plnkr.co/edit/qwX6vQ0mCHsfHKErly2R?p=preview). However it doesn't not represent the problem because it doesn't let me override the placeholder, but it can be useful for you in order to try to reproduce the situation locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by my own. I just set the `visibility` property of the placeholder to `hidden` like this:

```
#gplace::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    visibility: hidden;
}
#gplace::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    visibility: hidden;
}
#gplace:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    visibility: hidden;
}
#gplace:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue and I can't replicate your solution. Did you find a new workaround?